# How to make a div staying fixed centered on other div`s border line while changing browser size?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem finding out the code for making a fixed position of one div on another div`s edge line in the center and not getting the position changed when the browser size is changed.

Here is my code:

```
.box{
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #0060A3;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  position: relative;

}

  .two{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #FAA21B;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 92.5%;
}
```

I use margin-left: 92.5% for .two which makes it to the position in the center of the .box edge line, as I need it, but it only stays there if the browser is in 100% size. If I make it smaller, the .two is moving and it is not staying fixed in the middle.
[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I88Tn.png)

Comment: try with position : relative and margin-top also in % for .two box .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like @Hiren's answer, but here is an alternative:

```
.box{
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #0060A3;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  position: relative;

}

  .two{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #FAA21B;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;

  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

The important part being the last two lines..

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/86h5n423/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use after property for your layout check this

```css
.box{
  width:450px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid #0ff000;
  position:relative;
  background:#ffffff;
}
.box:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  right:-20px;
  top:1px;
  width:50px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid #ff0000; 
  background:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```